# How to checkout svn application using puppet manifest

Tags: puppet

My Requirement is to call manifest file in puppet using java code to checkout an application from svn and store it in the local folder in desktop..

1) I have to write a java code to call puppet Manifest in controller
2) Commands to call svn and checkout the application to local folder in Manifest file..

I am new to Puppet..
Can any one please help..
Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.. first of all please try to do it by yourself. And if u find any difficulties then post the question here

Answer (score 3):

You can use a puppet forge module to checkout repository.

Example with the vcsrepo module:

```
vcsrepo { '/tmp/vcstest-svn-checkout':
  ensure   => present,
  provider => svn,
  source   => 'http://svn.edgewall.org/repos/babel/trunk',
}
```

Source : https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/vcsrepo